# how to get Homography matrix using OpenCV (Stitching 2 images)

Tags: opencv, matrix, homography

I'm working on OpenCV in visual studio 2012 , i tried to get Homography matrix to Stitch 2 images in opencv  so really  i don't know the steps to follow to do'it :

[image]  [image]

Comment: Use `cv::findHomography` to find the perspective transformation: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography

Comment: can you give me one example for cv::findHomography

Comment: It's all there in the documentation. You just need to construct two vectors where the first contains the 2D coordinates from the first image and the second those from the second. All other parameters are optional. However, two points per image are probably too few for a good result.

Comment: but the vectors is in the form of points p1(x1, y1) p2(x2, y2) ??

Answer (score 8):

First you should be aware that two point correspondences, which you illustrate in your image, are not sufficient for homography estimation. A homography has 7 free parameters - there are 8 matrix elements, but a homography is a homogeneous quantity. This means you can scale the matrix as you like, which reduces the free parameters by one. To estimate 7 parameters you need at least four corresponding points.

I think understanding what you do is more important than blindly calling OpenCv methods, so please read about the real algorithms. The simplest (but non-optimal) method for homography computation is DLT, which amounts te rearranging the equation `y = Hx` for four or more points in order to solve for the components of `H` in a least squares sense. This is a nice explanation of the details:
https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/courses-i-teach/ECE661.08/solution/hw4_s1.pdf
The principal academic reference is Multiple View Geometry for Computer Vision by Heartley and Zisserman.

As pointed out in the comments, the OpenCv docs are here:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography

Comment: but if i chose a point p(x,y) in image1 i can't find exactly the same point with the same value in the image2

Comment: Please make sure you understand the role of Harris corner points in the PDF I linked. Here is more on that: https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/courses-i-teach/ECE661.08/solution/hw3_s1.pdf Also, google for "SIFT features".

Comment: @AHmédNet The problem with your images is that they have almost no overlapping whatsoever. This of course leads to the fact that you might not be able to find the required minimum of 4 matched keypoints. In such cases when feature matching fails (or you don't need it - depends on the task at hand) you might consider direct pixel-to-pixel comparison and accordingly you have to compute the correlation between the two images based on that.

Comment: As discussed in the answer below by riccardog, a 3x3 matrix has 9 elements and a fully general homography has 8 DoF, not 8 and 7, as described in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

To establish an homography between two images you need at least 4 points.
Each one has two coordinates, giving you two equations / constraints.
An homography has 8 degrees of freedom (it's a 3x3 full-rank matrix with 9 elements, -1 d.o.f. because of scale since it operates on homogeneous coordinates).

Note that only images of planar surfaces, or images taken by a camera rotating around its center can be related by an homography (in this latter case, the planar surface is the plane at infinity).

This [page](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html%22page%22) shows how to compute an homography with feature extraction and RANSAC.